# JDBC and Spring connection pool

Tags: spring, jdbc, database-connection, connection-pooling, autocommit

I would like to use connection pool for a web app and mysql dbms.
If I have want to force the connection to set autocommit to false for a particular method, is it possibile that this connection (with autocommitt off) is used by other requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possibile that this connection (with autocommitt off) is used by other requests?

You should always retrieve the `Connection` in the narrowest scope, this means, preferably as a local variable for your methods. Then, you can turn autocommit off by calling [`Connection#setAutocommit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit-boolean-) with `false`, and after using the connection object, **close it**. Note that this will only affect the current transaction and other requests won't be affected.

Comment: But this way if in a request I have many stuff to do with the database I will open and close many many connection is it s good idea? I thought that connection pool was used to avoid this.

Comment: @Tobia I just said you have to open a `Connection` in the narrowest scope possible. This doesn't mean you can reuse the same opened `Connection` along several methods (usually, as a parameter).

Comment: @Tobia using a connection pool doesn't mean you should not close the connection. You **must always** close it, then the connection pool will take care of the *closed* physical connection and put it in SLEEP mode or something else instead of closing it (but that's the work of the database connection pool).

Comment: Is this valid also for JdbcTemplate? I saw many NamedParameterJdbcDaoSupport examples without the connection close.

Comment: @Tobia in JdbcTemplate for Spring you don't open the connection manually, the framework do it for you. And the framework close it for you as well.